# Can't delete a ghost file in my .NET Web Site that prevents publishing

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, web

This is really frustrating me. I file I have continually gets recreated, but not really. It appears in my project, it appears in Windows Explorer, but I can't open it, it says the file doesn't exist. If I try to delete it, it says it cannot find the item, BUT if I try to delete it, it says it failed, then refresh, the file is gone. But if I go back into my project and refresh the directory, it shows up again both in the project and explorer.

Now I've read this can be caused if you have low RAM and are doing a lot of operations, however I've got 16gb ram and just am using one instance of VS, so that can't be it. I've also read that restarting the computer helps. Well when I restart, I can see the file there sometimes, sometimes not. If it's there I can F5 and it's gone. BUT as soon as I either try an SVN update (even though it doesn't update/add anything in the svn log box), or try and build the project, or just refresh the directory from within visual studio again, the ghost file appears.

This is preventing me from publishing the website because every time I go to publish it, it throws an error telling me that ghost file is missing. But there is no file indicator in the error message and searching the entire solution for any references to it returns no results...so I am at a loss for what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best suggestion is to create a new Web Site project in a different folder and copy the files over. It sounds like your project file is damaged.

Alternatively, this could be caused by Adding an existing item as a Link, which by default doesn't get included when you publish a (web) project.

Comment: Yeah that is what I wanted to avoid but ended up doing anyway. =/